# Simple Discord chatbot written in Python that serves as a dictionary with multiple data sources

Tags: python, dictionary, split, datasource, chatbot

I would like to help my translator community on Discord with a chatbot that functions as a dictionary, a vocabulary database, but the size of the wordpool is going to be massive, and I want to split the datasource into several separate files as they do with initial letters' alphabetical index in printed dictionaries. I have a base program code, it already works with one file, but I do not know how to implement the multi-file look-up and evaluation method. Sorry for my bad English (it is not my native language, evidently)! Also, bear with me, please, as I am a noob in programming!
Could you help me with this, please?

These are my files. It is intended to answer to private messages and communicate in DM only.

My datasource #1
**pool0_help.py**

```
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    
    #HELP MESSAGE
    #------------

    if p_message == '?help':
        return 'Type in any name or phrase that comes to your mind, and I will tell you what its equivalent is in your language.\r\n \r\nTo see all phrases under index B, type: poolB'

    #FALLBACK
    #--------

    return 'I am not sure I understood it correctly!'
```

My would-be datasource #3
**pool2_B.py**

```
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    
    #INDEX B
    #-------
    
    poolB = [
        "**baldur\'s gate**" , 
        "**baldur\'s mouth gazette**" , 
        "**beastlands**" , 
        "**blighted village**" , 
        "**blushing mermaid**"
    ]
    
    if p_message == "b-index":
        return '? *B* ::\r\n> ' + str(poolB)

    if p_message == 'baldur\'s gate':
        return '? *' + p_message + '*\r\n= **Baldurkapuja**'

    if p_message == 'baldur\'s mouth gazette':
        return '? *' + p_message + '*\r\n= **Baldur Szája Hírmondó**'

    if p_message == 'beastlands':
        return '? *' + p_message + '*\r\n= **Fenevadföld**'

    if p_message == 'blighted village':
        return '? *' + p_message + '*\r\n= **Felégetett falu**'

    if p_message == 'blushing mermaid':
        return '? *' + p_message + '*\r\n= **Piruló sellő**'

    #FALLBACK
    #--------

    return 'There is no such word, name or pharse in my database, sorry!'
```

**bot.py**

```
import discord
import pool0_help
import pool1_A
import pool2_B
import pool3_C

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = pool0_help.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.author.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'my Discord token'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    #intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" in ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '!':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

**main.py**

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

As I mentioned before, it works as expected with one datasource (in this example: 'pool0_help.py'). But no matter how I try, I can't get it work with more files.

It would be inconvenient to store in and cumbersome to edit one file with hundreds of words, that is why I want to split it into smaller wordpools.

Would you be so kind and show me what to modify and how to make this dictionary work, please? It would be a huge help for us! Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your answer and update with the exact error message (the lines starting with `Traceback (most recent call last):`)? Thank you!

Comment: Or, is there not an error? In that case, what is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: Hello David, When I run the script with one imported source file ('pool0_help.py'), it gives no error at all, it works as it should. My problem is that I lack the necessary skills to add an other (or more) sources, and reach to a working solution. Which should be the following: when someone makes a query with a word that is starting with the letter 'A', the program should pick the answer from the corresponding file ('pool1_A.py'), and ignore all other fallbacks. When one makes their query with a 'B'-word, they should get their answer from other wordpool ('pool2_B.py). And so on, and so forth.

Comment: I posted an answer to your problem below.

Comment: Sir, method #2 works like a charm! I had to add one line to method #1 to make it work, because without it I only got "answers" from the first pool-file, but not from the others. For every word that was not in the firstly imported file I got the following error message: "400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message". So I did a little digging, and found a solution that utilizes 'if response:' before the first 'await' command(?). With this addition, method #1 also works as you described in your answer. I am really grateful for your help! My problem is solved, thanks to you!

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry I forgot that line there… I’ll fix it. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow determine which `pool` you need to use for each incoming message. You have two choices here: either try each pool until one of them works, or create some logic that determines the pool beforehand.

---

**Method one: Trying each pool until it works**

To try each pool, you can put the pools into a `list` and just call `get_response` until you get something. If you choose this, then the `get_response` functions in the pools should return `None` if a response is not matched (i.e. no return statement). For example:

```py
# pool0_help.py
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == '?help':
        return 'Type in any name or phrase that comes to your mind, and I will tell you what its equivalent is in your language.\r\n \r\nTo see all phrases under index B, type: poolB'
```

```py
# pool2_B.py
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    poolB = [
        "**baldur\'s gate**" , 
        "**baldur\'s mouth gazette**" , 
        "**beastlands**" , 
        "**blighted village**" , 
        "**blushing mermaid**"
    ]
    
    if p_message == "b-index":
        return '? *B* ::\r\n> ' + str(poolB)

    # a bunch more `if`s...
```

```py
# bot.py
import pool0_help
import pool1_A
import pool2_B
import pool3_C

POOLS = [pool0_help, pool1_A, pool2_B, pool3_C, ...]

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        for pool in POOLS:
            response = pool.get_response(user_message)
            if not response:
                continue
            await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.author.send(response)
            return
        await message.author.send('Unknown message') if is_private else await message.author.send('Unknown message')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# ... rest of your code ...
```

---

**Method two: Using the pool corresponding to the first letter**

To check the pool to use beforehand, you can create a `dict` from the first letter to the `pool` module object. Your `bot.py` might look like:

```py
# bot.py
import pool0_help
import pool1_A
import pool2_B
import pool3_C

POOLS = {'?': pool0_help, 'a': pool1_A, 'b': pool2_B, 'c': pool3_C, ...}

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        ch = user_message[0]
        if ch not in POOLS:
            await message.author.send('Unknown message') if is_private else await message.author.send('Unknown message')
        response = POOLS[ch].get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.author.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# ... rest of your code ...
```